# How to send data through http transformation in Informatica?

Tags: api, salesforce, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have http request as follows
[
{
"id":"xxxxxxx"
"email":"xxxxx@.com"
}
]

I need to update the fields by calling rest API through http transformation. Do I need to use POST , simple post or simple put in http method?

```
Below is the expression i used for json file format
'[' || chr(10) || ' {' || chr(10) || '  "Id":"'|| id || ' "' || chr(10) || ' "email": "'|| email || '"' || chr(10) || ' }' || chr(10) || ']'
```

I was able to get the required format. Now the question is configuring the http transformation. I am sending this string to input and using simple post and the output I connected to flat file for http response. Wondering if the URL provided is correct or is there any authentication needed with username and password. Attached are the images[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tRDS.png)

Comment: it may be simple post. API should take care of update or insert or select. I remember your last question. This seems same question. Are you facing nay issues with the solution i gave? can you post error message.

Comment: i have edited the question . i was able to get json format without " values now the query is regarding the http transformation. confusion is with the URL provided to me, it is not looking like complete URL. And is there anything I need to configure on the header option this is all I want to know.

Comment: now it got processsed but got an error stating [{"errorcode":"URL not reset","message":Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set"}]

im connecting to rest api (salesforce)

Comment: test the url using swagger

Comment: okay. Is there any other configuration missing regarding the URL i read here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217951/url-not-reset-error-rest-api

Comment: I see one of your post regarding how to post bearer token in header in http transformation.. Can you share how you're sending the username and password , how you stored it in the mapping. I posted a post regarding the same since the rest webservice developer informed sending consumer key which we need to pass to connect to rest webservice

Comment: sure i wil reply

Comment: i added an EDIT to the question. if it helps, will be glad.